# The curious case of the cannabis cat?

Tags: cats, safety, poison

I have a 7-year-old British shorthair cat that sleeps next to me every night. I vape cannabis oil as a sleep aid a few times a week, usually while reading or watching a movie just before sleep. I do my best to exhale away from his general direction but he noticeably smells it. I usually keep the windows open and he definitely doesn't *seem* to mind it (always stays, never runs off, no obvious adverse reactions).

Occasionally he will actually get up to smell(breathe?!) the vapor that I exhale. I usually shoo him away from it.

How are cats affected by second-hand cannabis oil vapor? Are there any adverse effects on my cat's temperament and/or health? Should I be shooing? Am I an irresponsible cat-dad?

Comment: On the serious side, yes but depending on the concentration in the air and time exposed. They have faster metabolism and assimilate drugs different. On the joke side, stop the catnip. Both.

Answer (score 4):

### Curious cats

Your cat will be influenced by cannabis even in low doses so it is best to avoid this. Many cats are curious of what you do and that extents to when you consume cannabis.

### Cannabis smoke

I do not know how dangerous cannabis smoke is to cats, but I am not willing to find out. So may I suggest you keep your cat away from inhaling the vapour just to be safe.

While the effects of cannabis on humans are well know, on [cats way less](https://www.thespruce.com/is-marijuana-toxic-to-cats-555055).

So the [smoke is not the big issue](https://vcahospitals.com/know-your-pet/marijuana-intoxication-in-dogs-and-cats), but if your cat starts eating the oil you use, that might kill it.

> Luckily, marijuana intoxication is seldom fatal.

*tldr: drugs have different effects on different species. What might be safe(ish) for humans can be lethal for pets. With many substances having unknown effects on pets.*